# Change async-shell-command with a synchronous command keeping the dynamically displayed buffer

Tags: shell-command, async

I have this snippet of code:

```
(async-shell-command
 (concat "perl myscript.pl " (buffer-name))
 (read-string "RETURN: ")
 (with-temp-file "file.new"
   (insert-file-contents "file.new")
   (perform-replace "REGEXP" 
            "REPLACEMENT" 
            nil nil nil 1 nil (point-min) (point-max))))
```

This makes my `perl` script run on the file visited by buffer and returns a file `file.new`. I can see the `stdout` displayed  dynamically  in the buffer `\*Async Shell Command\*`, **step by step**. Then I need to perform some replacements in `file.new`. Because of the asyncronicity of the process I need to put a `read-string` to pause my elisp program.

I'd like to sobstitute the `async-shell-command` with a *synchronous* command but keeping the dynamically diplayed buffer.

**Addedum.** Here's another little example of what I mean:

```
(async-shell-command "echo \"bye\"; sleep 3; echo \"bye\"")
```

this code will display the first "bye" string in the  *Async Shell Command* buffer, than the second "bye" string will be displayed after 3 seconds.

I'd like to have `shell-command` behaving the same, e.g.:

```
(shell-command "echo \"bye\"; sleep 3; echo \"bye\"")
```

I tried to modify the `async-shell-command` this way:

```
(defun my-sync-shell-command (command &optional output-buffer error-buffer)
  "DocString"
  (interactive
   (list
    (read-shell-command "Sync shell command: " nil nil
            (let ((filename
                   (cond
                (buffer-file-name)
                ((eq major-mode 'dired-mode)
                 (dired-get-filename nil t)))))
              (and filename (file-relative-name filename))))
    current-prefix-arg
    shell-command-default-error-buffer))
  ;; I commented these lines to remove the ending "&" sign:
  ;; (unless (string-match "&[ \t]*\\'" command)
  ;;   (setq command (concat command)))
  (shell-command command output-buffer error-buffer))
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know what the output buffer is, you can hack around this issue by getting the process object from the output buffer and then waiting for it to finish.

```
(defun run-kinda-async-shell-command (command &optional output-buffer)
  "Run `command' and send results to `output-buffer', blocking until the command finishes."
  (interactive "sCommand: \nsBuffer: ")
  (async-shell-command command output-buffer)
  (let ((process (get-buffer-process output-buffer)))
    (while (process-live-p process)
      (sit-for 0.2))))
```

Example Usage:

```
(progn
  (message "prints before")
  (run-kinda-async-shell-command "echo 1 && sleep 2 && echo 1" "output-test")
  (message "prints after"))
```

Comment: `(while (process-live-p (get-buffer-process "*Async Shell Command*")) (sit-for 0.2))` does the job. I'll wait a couple of days before accept your answer.